# Check available network ports in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, port

Administrator is blocking some network ports, but some are left open (e.g. 80). Is there a portable utility to check what ports are blocked?

Using Windows 7 32-bit

Answer (score 3):

[ShieldsUP](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) will rapidly scan all ports, from the Internet to your IP address.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try [Nmap](http://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html) for Windows, it's a Unix network mapping tool ported to Windows.